# How can i add a button in transparent section of navigation drawer in android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

how can i add a button in transparent section of navigation drawer or listen touch listener on it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by transparent section of navigation drawer. Please explain your question. Or some one will downvote you

Comment: I mean 'transparent section' where we can touch on it to close navigation.